# the very... himself

Tags: redundancy

> -- I don't understand why he said one thing and then went on to do another!
>
> -- Well, I would ask ***the very*** man ***himself***.

My question is, can "very" be used together with "himself" in such a situation, or am I saying twice the same thing?

I could give more examples, like

> He was referring to ***the very*** book ***itself***.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common **idiomatic pleonasm** used in order to emphasis that the specific person who can shed light on a subject is in fact available directly to answer questions.

To use the same construction in another context (as in your "book" example) is not as common, and in fact I can't call to mind an occasion of where I've seen it being used.

But "the very man himself / the very woman herself" is common.